# Postman (Rest API Web Service, Spring Security) - Authentication without logging in

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, postman

I am using a Spring Security, Restful WebService and Postman Rest Clien. i want to test my Restful WebService using the Postman without logging in and I do put a `@Secured("AMIN_ROLE")` to my methods for Restful webservice in order to secured the method, and using the POSTMAN Authorization tab i also put a Digest Auth which is the username and password with already MD5 format. now my problem is I cannot test my restful webservice using the Postman it will prompt a UNAUTHORIZED. please help me for this stuff...

security.xml

```
<security:http 
        use-expressions="true" 
        entry-point-ref="authEntryPoint">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>

</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="authProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="authProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="md5Encoder"/>
</bean>

<bean id="md5Encoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>
<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.shindi.ippan.service.UserAccountService"/>
```

UserAccountService.java

```
@Service("userAccountService")
```

public class UserAccountService extends AbstractService implements UserDetailsService{

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userAccountRepository")
IRepository<UserAccount> repository;

@Override
protected IRepository<UserAccount> getRepository() {
    return repository;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserAccount userAccount = ((UserAccountRepository)repository).readByUsername(username);

    return userAccount;
}
```

}

UserAccount.java implements UserDetails

ApplicationAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

```
@Component("authEntryPoint")
```

public class ApplicationAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

```
@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException ae) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "MENSAHE UNAUTHORIZED");
}
```

}

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

UserAccountController.java

```
@Controller
```

@RequestMapping("/userAccount")
public class UserAccountController extends AbstractController {

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userAccountService")
IService<UserAccount> service;

@Override
public IService<UserAccount> getService() {
    return service;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody UserAccount login( String username, String password ){
    UserAccount userAccount = ((UserAccountService)service).loadUserByUsername(username);
    return userAccount;
}

@Secured("ADMIN_ROLE")
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String test(){
    return "test...";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/denied", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String denied(){
    return "denied...";
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please elaborate by putting the configuration files and dummy code of your web services ?

Comment: please see code above... now my problem is I cannot test my restful webservice using the Postman it will prompt a UNAUTHORIZED. please help me for this stuff...